# C++ wrapper pass pointer address to native class

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli, clr, managed, mixed-mode

Hello I am trying to pass a pointer address from a managed class to an unmanaged 
class. So every A-Object has a reference to a B-object. But if I pass the reference in `_a = new A(_managedB->_b)` the compiler throws an error that no constructor matches the argument list.

So what's wrong with the code?

unmanaged code:

```
class A
{
private:
    B &b;
public:
    explicit
        A(B& b);
        ~A();
}
```

managed code:

```
public ref class ManagedA
{
private:
    ManagedB ^_managedB;
    A *_a;
public:
    ManagedA::ManagedA(ManagedB ^managedB ): _managedB(managedB)
    {
        _a = new A(_managedB->_b);
    }
    ManagedA::~ManagedA(ManagedB ^managedB ): _managedB(managedB)
    {
        delete _a;
        _a = 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: A managed pointer and an unmanaged reference are not the same thing. You need to pin the object.

Comment: You can't take a (native) reference to (or address of) a managed object -- you either have to pin it in memory (otherwise the GC has the right to move it around willy nilly) or use managed references (`ManagedB^`).

Comment: So I tried folowing: pin_ptr<B> pointerB = _managedB->_b; _a = new A(pointerB); Whats is wrong with this? Sorry for the questions, but I am new in managed C++. Has anybody an example for this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I did it like this and it worked.
I don't know if the situation is interpreted right, but I am not trying to pass a Handle as a pointer. I pass a pointer that is a member of an Handle.

```
public ref class ManagedA
{
private:
    ManagedB ^_managedB;
    A *_a;
public:
    ManagedA::ManagedA(ManagedB ^managedB ): _managedB(managedB)
    {
        _a = new A(*_managedB->_b);
    }
    ManagedA::~ManagedA(ManagedB ^managedB ): _managedB(managedB)
    {
        delete _a;
        _a = 0;
    }
};
```